# openxlsx write R dataframe to XLSX with cell reference from worksheet to another

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, excel-formula, openxlsx

I am trying to write formulas from an R dataframe to XLSX file. I want to reference data from one worksheet in another using cell references. One worksheet is suppposed to be a "database" and then the other sheet is supposed to have the "formula" which references data from the "database" sheet.

**The R code:**

```
require(openxlsx)

# create workbook ---------------------------------------------------------

wb <- createWorkbook()

# add worksheets ----------------------------------------------------------

addWorksheet(wb, "database")
addWorksheet(wb, "database space")
addWorksheet(wb, "reference")

# make database -----------------------------------------------------------

df1 <- data.frame(
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    formula_1 = "A2 + B2"
)

## change class to formula
class(df1$formula_1) <- c(class(df1$formula_1), "formula")

# prepare formula ---------------------------------------------------------

df2 <- data.frame(
    formula_2 = "$database.A2",
    formula_3 = "$'database space'.B2"
)

# change class to formula
class(df2$formula_2) <- c(class(df2$formula_2), "formula")
class(df2$formula_3) <- c(class(df2$formula_3), "formula")

# write to XLSX file ------------------------------------------------------

writeData(wb, sheet = "database", x = df1)
writeData(wb, sheet = "database space", x = df1)
writeData(wb, sheet = "reference", x = df2)

# open XLSX file ----------------------------------------------------------

openXL(wb)
```

The usual way of adding a formula works. In the openend XLSX file this is demonstrated in cell C3 of worksheet `database` and `database space`. But, when opening worksheet `formula`, my issue presents itself (see screenshot 1). Cells A2 and B2 both show `#NAME?` and not the value of the other worksheets.

[image: screenshot 1]

However, when I add the cell reference manually, it works (see screenshot 2).

[image: screenshot 2]

**`openxlsx` version**

```
> packageVersion("openxlsx")
[1] ‘4.0.17’
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Boy, I dearly wish you had not used the name `formula` for your function. It's the name of such a core R function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have renamed the objects to `df1` and `df2`. Do you have any idea how I can solve my problem @42-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here are the names that are passed to `df2`. The solution to the problem is to remove the `$` and replace the `.` with a `!`.

Replacing `df2` in the code above with the following works:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
    formula_2 = "database!A2",
    formula_3 = "'database space'!B2"
)
```

The character strings are now evaluated as formulas and correctly reference cells from other sheets. I found the solution by working through the `XLConnect` R package, where an example in the help file for `setCellFormula-methods` includes a formula as a reference to a separate sheet.